# Create function in ruby is returning ActiveRecord::Relation object rather than the actual record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, create-react-app

Im creating two objects and then passing them to the view with the redirect_to function.
The Order object is fine and usable in the view, but the Message object is of the type ActiveRecord::Relation and any call to message.variable get a noMethodError.  Heres the code

Controller code:

```
      @order = Order.create(order_params.merge(
        child: child, 
        address: prevOrderInfo.address,
        zipcode: prevOrderInfo.zipcode,
        user_facing_id: SecureRandom.uuid[0..7]))

      @message = Message.create(message_params.merge(:order_id => @order.id))

      redirect_to order_path(@order, @message)
```

View inspection returns

```
#order object
--- '#<Order id: 8, user_facing_id: "d1791380", product_id: 1, child_id: 2, shipping_name:
  "Marge Simpson", address: "742 Evergreen Terrace", zipcode: "58008", paid: true,
  created_at: "2019-09-30 19:29:01", updated_at: "2019-09-30 19:29:01">'
#message object
--- '#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id: 6, full_name: "Homer ", email: "homer@gmial.com",
  message: "This is a message", order_id: 8, created_at: "2019-09-30 19:29:01", updated_at:
  "2019-09-30 19:29:01">]>'
```

html.erb uses @order just fine.
`<%= @order.child.full_name %>`
puts "Maggie Simpson" into the web page

But any usage of @message like `<%= @message.full_name %>`
gets a noMethodError for full_name

Not sure what Im doing, but why would the create call for the Order table return one type and another for the Message table?

Answer (score 0):

`@message` seems to be a collection of some sort. You should be able to call `<%= @message.first.full_name %>` or you can either iterate over it and do the following:

```
<% @message.each do |msg| %>
  <%= msg.full_name %>
<% end %>
```

OR you can change your code to do the redirect as follows:
`redirect_to order_path(@order, message_id: @message.id)`

in the order show action you will then have:

`@order = Order.find(params[:id])`

`@message = Message.find(params[:message_id])`

With this approach, you'll then have a `@order` object and an `@message` object available in your view.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give that a try, but my real issue is why does create function return two different types?

Comment: The issue was in the show method.  I set @message using Message.where....
Thank you so much!!

Comment: No prob, Anytime!! :)